# UITableView not scrolling all the way to top after resorting dynamic size cells and setting content offset to top

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableview with dynamically sized cells, and a button that toggles the sort order of these cells. I'd like to scroll to the top every time the sort order is toggled, but when I set the content offset to the top, it seems to only scroll ~90% of the way there.

The offsetting code is simple enough and has served me well on different projects, so I seriously doubt the problem is here:

```
- (void) scrollToTop
 {
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top);
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What value does "self.tableView.contentInset.top" print in the debugger?  Maybe contentInset.bottom would return the proper value.

Comment: 64, the standard inset for UITableViews embedded in controllers with transparent UINavigationBars. The `-self.tableView.contentInset.top` is the idiomatic way of saying "top of the tableview" so I'm sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't think I would find the answer so soon.

I was using UITableView's `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` to return my minimum cell height, and it seems that the tableview uses this inside `reloadData` to create an idea of how big the content is before actually dequeuing the cells and caching their height. Being halfway down the content and reloading the data causes the tableview to think the distance to the top is the (number of cells offscreen above the current visible * the minimum height from `estimatedHeightForRow`), causing the tableview to only offset itself as if all cells were the minimum height. My solution was just to avoid using the estimated height, since my tableview isn't excessively long anyway. If you do have a large tableview (approaching 1000+ rows) that actually needs to use the estimated values for performance reasons, you might want to find a way to make the estimated values as close to the runtime values as possible, or look into more detailed solutions.

tl;dr - Remove `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and just allow the tableView to size itself from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 5):

```
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // Lets update with whatever info we have
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

reloading and then scrolling resolved for me.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this instead?

```
NSIndexPath *start = = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:start atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that was my first attempt and it seems the tableView really just uses that to determine what CGPoint to send to `setContentOffset:`

Comment: Ah, sorry to waste your time.  Just going for the obvious possibility first.  Glad you figured out your answer.

Comment: Not a waste of time at all! Thanks for your effort and concern.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. It doesn't seem to always be the case. it has a different trigger it seems. and when removing dynamic sizing it's not an option - it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. The solution was to call `layoutIfNeeded()` before setting the content offset:

```
tableView.reloadData();
tableView.layoutIfNeeded();
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.Empty, animated: true);
```